# Response.write(script) is not working.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, progress-bar

I'm writing a program in ASP.NET with a VB backend. I am trying to get a popup window  to open using javascript prior to a subroutine running, and close it when the routine ends as a way to provide a progress indicator to the user, as some of these subroutine calls can take a few minutes.

My code is below.

```
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>function openWin() {myWindow = window.open('Status.aspx?FileName=" & gstrCurrentFile & "&FileNumber=" & gCurrentItem & "&Total=" & gTotal & "', 'Status', 'width=200, height=100');};</script>")
    RunOACW2()
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>function closeWin() {myWindow.close();}</script>")
```

However, I never see a popup, but I am pretty sure the javascript is correct. What is going wrong?

Comment: `trying to get a popup window via javascript prior to a subroutine running, and close it when the routine ends` it doesn't work like that. The entire response is generated, then sent to the client. Even if you got the popups to work, you'd see them all at the same time. If you want to provide a progress indicator, you'll need to use AJAX or SignalR.

Comment: is there a (better) way to provide some kind of progress indicator?

Comment: it's nowhere in the html or any js file... I'm trying to just write to it dynamically in the btn_click event.

Comment: What you can do is show an [indetermine progress bar](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/progressbar/indeterminate.html) OnClientClick. Then when the postback completes the progress bar won't be there. Or use an UpdatePanel (which uses AJAX underneath) with an UpdateProgress control (which will also be indeterminate). Note, I don't recommend UpdatePanel. What I recommend is kicking the entire function off using jQuery AJAX, then polling the server for progress data every couple of seconds. That would allow you to show the actual progress instead of indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowAlertMessage()
{
alert("button clicked"); //instead of alert, you should do something else. alert stops the whole JavaScript execution, but it's good enough for example purposes.
}
</script>
<asp:Button id="Btn1" Text="Click me!" OnClientClick="ShowAlertMessage();" OnClick="Btn1_Click" />
```

The JavaScript function will execute. Then when it's done executing, the page will begin the postback to the server.

From server side, you could use [RegisterClientStartupScript](http://forums.asp.net/t/1060981.aspx?RegisterClientStartupScript%20and%20RegisterClientScriptBlock%20not%20working) to display an alert message when it's done. But plain JavaScript alert boxes suck. They demand the user's attention and can't be styled.

Instead of using an alert, just show an indeterminate progress bar or a label that says "Loading...". Once the postback completes, that can go away. Or you could use a notification library such as [Noty](http://ned.im/noty/) to display a loading message.

Comment: I know this will work to get a single popup, but that I can do by simply making a progress panel visible prior to kicking off the subroutine, and then hiding it upon completion... I was hoping for a way to show something that changed dynamically as different subroutines were called, and then completed...

Comment: @Jon Then you must use an AJAX or SignalR based solution. And posting a solution related to that is a little too broad. Instead, learn how to use AJAX (again, I recommend [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) because it's simple) and [web services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337535/Understanding-the-Basics-of-Web-Service-in-ASP-NET) to execute the server side stuff, and use AJAX  to poll the server for status updates.

Comment: ok, that's kind of where I thought this was headed... do you know a good resource for ajax? I've used little stuff before, panel extenders and whatnot, but nothing like this progress stuff, or anything that interacted with a db before...

Comment: also, would that mean that all the code for db manipulation would have to be ported to an ajax related tool?

Comment: @Jon No. You still handle the DB interaction on the server side using your server side tools (in your case, VB.NET and .NET framework). You just kick off the server side execution and check the status from the client side (JavaScript).